# Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600002c51ec0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'AlphabetController''

Tags: swift, storyboard, identifier

```
 @objc func abcPressed() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: AlphabetController.storyboardIdentifier) as! AlphabetController
            
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

When I pressed abcPressed, had an error "Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600002c51ec0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'AlphabetController"

How to identify AlphabetController by code?

Please help me! Thanks You

```
class AlphabetController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let alphabet = ["A", "Ă", "Â", "B", "C", "D", "Đ", "E", "Ê", "G", "H", "I", "K", "M", "N", "O", "Ô", "Ơ", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "Ư", "V", "X", "Y"]
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        }
```

I tried

```
extension AlphabetController {
    static var storyboardIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
```

Comment: Did you add `AlphabetController` to your storyboard at all?

Comment: How do you add it?

Comment: You set the identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: Can you give more detailed instructions? @HangarRash

Comment: A UIViewController isn’t automatically a storyboard you have to assign it to one. This is usually done in one of the first few steps of any tutorial such as the “iOS Dev tutorials” from Apple I suggest looking at them it will make the learning process much simpler than guessing your way through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Identifier in Storyboard:

[image]

Note that it can be any string - for example, one might use: "alphaVC" - it does not need to match the name of the View Controller class.